# Problem with CreatePage API using gatsby and contentful

Tags: graphql, gatsby, contentful

I am trying to generate pages of individual team members using data from contentful. Creating page using contentful data is secondary, my primary concern is that the gatsby-node.js file is unable to create pages with the /${node.slug}

This is the gatsby-node.js file

```
exports.createPages = async ({ graphql, actions, reporter }) => {
  const result = await graphql(`
     {
      allContentfulIndividualTeamMember {
        nodes {
          slug
        }
      }
    }
  `);
  if (result.error) {
    reporter.panic("error loading data", JSON.stringify(result.errors))
  }
  result.data.allContentfulIndividualTeamMember.nodes.forEach(node => {
    actions.createPage({
      path: `/${node.slug}`,
      component: require.resolve("./src/Templates/individualTeamPage.js"),
      context: {
        slug: node.slug,
      },
    })
  })
}
```

This is my individual team member template file

```
import React from "react"
import { graphql } from "gatsby"
const IndividualTeamPage = ({ data }) => {
  console.log("checking ")
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Checking</h1>
      <p>{data.edges.node.nameOfTheEmployee} </p>
    </div>
  )
}

export default IndividualTeamPage
export const query = graphql(`
  query($slug: String!) {
    allContentfulIndividualTeamMember(filter: { slug: { eq: $slug } }) {
      edges {
        node {
          positionInTheCompany
          nameOfTheEmployee
        }
      }
    }
  }
`)
```

**Update:**
I thought the issue was caused by me changing the pages folder in gatsby to Pages, I changed to back to pages and removed and installed node_modules. I am still unable to create pages programmatically, if it helps [success run page queries - 0.035s - 3/3] I get this in the the terminal whenever I run gatsby develop

Comment: Make sure that the field slug is returning something. Can you show us terminal output error or graphql playground error?

Answer (score 2):

`` Looks like it's graphql`<Content>` not graphql(`<Content`)> ``

Comment: Yes it should be graphql`QUERY`. check out the Gatsby documentation for more info.
https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/page-query/

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you are retrieving values from Contentful with that query? My guess is:

```
  const result = graphql(`
    query {
      allContentfulIndividualTeamMember { 
       edges {
          node {
            slug
          }
        }
      } 
    }   
`)
```

Note the `edges` object and the `node` (instead of node**s**).

So your loop object would be: `result.data.allContentfulIndividualTeamMember.edges.node.forEach()`

Comment: I don't think this is the issue, I am sure that the my code is retrieving values, what I noticed now is initially I renamed that pages folder in gatsby as Pages. The file system is unable to find the pages one, I've changed it to pages now, it messed up the local node modules, I removed it and did an npm i again, no luck there. I guess I'll have to redo this pages part of the project in a new one

Comment: That information is not provided in the question. Would you like to edit it and reask? Of course, that's the issue. The filesystem of Gatsby works in a specific naming and path way. Changing it requires a lot of changes in the project to keep the initial workaround.